# How to use 2 classes for the same function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I run the same click function for 2 classes ?

I have this :

```
$('.buythis').click(function(){ blabla }
```

And I want to use the same line for a different class like :

```
    $('.anotherclass').click(function(){ blabla }
```

Now ... how can I use the same click function without redeclaring it ?
i want something like :

```
          ($('.buythis'),$('.anotherclass')).click(function(){ blabla }
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
 $('.buythis, .anotherclass').click(function(){ blabla }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a comma between the two selectors:

```
$('.buythis, .anotherclass').click( ... );
```

or use two selectors chained with [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

```
$('.buythis').add('.anotherclass').click( ... );
```

The latter syntax can be useful if the selectors are complicated since it can remove ambiguity from the selector parser and make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple selector<sup>[1](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)</sup>:

```
$('.buythis, .anotherclass').click(function(){ blabla });
```

Answer (score 1):

Then use following code :

```
$('.buythis, .anotherclass').click(function(){ blabla }
```